# Audio streaming (mp3 files and shoutcast radio stream) in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

What is the best npm package to build an application capable of streaming audio files and shoutcast radio streams. I have viewed Videogular2 and other packages but can't decide which of them is better.

Comment: My advice is to use vanilla Javascript framework for that, like jPlayer or SoundManager 2. I don't think that ng2 can help you with playing streams, it has a different purpose.